# Retriving data from div and header classes using pyhton urllib.request and bs4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a python program which is capable of getting the objects title and its cost from 'https://coinmarketcap.com/' website. in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLAnO.png) i have my initial code. I keep getting an error that says:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

however, both the 'priceHeading' & 'priceValue' class have values of 'bitcoin price' and '29,000' respectively. How do I get those values?

here's my initial code:

```
# import libraries
import urllib.request as ur
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

quote_page = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/'

page = ur.urlopen(quote_page)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

name_box = soup.find('h1', attrs={'class': 'priceHeading'})

name = name_box.text.strip() 
print (name)

price_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'priceValue'})
price = price_box.text
print (price)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably received compressed response from the server which `urllib.request` cannot handle. Instead of `urllib.request` use `requests` module:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

quote_page = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(quote_page).content, "html.parser")
name_box = soup.find("h1", attrs={"class": "priceHeading"})

name = name_box.text.strip()
print(name)

price_box = soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "priceValue"})
price = price_box.text
print(price)
```

Prints:

```
Bitcoin Price (BTC)
$29,919.86
```